# Printing text between a specific word and a closing paranthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text-mining

I have a text document out of which I want to extract specific Names based on the context. For example, a part of a sentence in the document goes like- "...TO INTERVIEW VICTIM #1 (!ARIEL B. JOHNSON) ...". I want to print just the name between the parenthesis but also want it to be searched using "VICTIM #1" for context.

I have tried the following code. doc['sentence'] is the dataframe column where all the sentences of the document are stored as rows.

```py
SearchStr = 'VICTIM \#1 (.*?\))'

victim = re.search(SearchStr, str(doc['sentence']))

if victim:
    print(victim.groups())
print(victim)
```

It should be printing 'ARIEL B. JOHNSON'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match = re.search(r"VICTIM #[0-9]+ \(.*?\)",STRING)
```

returns

'VICTIM #1 (!ARIEL B. JOHNSON)'

which you could split into a dictionary of victim #s and names if you wanted? if that helps?

```
name = re.sub(r'VICTIM #[0-9]+\s+|!*\(*\)*','',match.group())
num = re.search('[0-9]+',match.group()).group()

v = {num,name}
```

this can be adapted to any victim # or name

to apply this over every row in the df use it as a function then apply it over the column:

```
def victim(STRING):
    match = re.search(r"VICTIM #[0-9]+ \(.*?\)",STRING)
    name = re.sub(r'VICTIM #[0-9]+\s+|!*\(*\)*','',match.group())
    num = re.search('[0-9]+',match.group()).group()
    v.update({num:name})

doc['sentence'].apply(victim)
```

this gives you a dict with all the victim #s/names

Comment: How do I run it through the whole dataframe column to find the match?

Comment: Running this script on my data frame gave me the error 'expected string or bytes-like object'. Tried converting the data to string but didn't help. I had to run it on the raw text to get required result. Thanks anyways!